# Update data from one table to another with no common identifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2012, inner-join, union-all

I'd like to have a query (SQL Server 2012) do the following:
Update data from one table to another where there is no common linkable record (pretty sure I can't just join and then update).  only similarity is that the tables are of the same structure

to keep it simple (transferring 100+ items)

- Table 1a: KEY, TagName <-- Where a.TagName like 'Tag1'
- Table 1b:  DS_KEY, Make, Model <-- source of the Update data
- Table 2a: KEY, TagName <-- Where b.TagName like 'Tag2'
- Table 2b:  DS_KEY, Make, Model <-- destination of the Update data

so,

- Table 1a: 123, Tag1
- Table 1b: 123, Test1, Model1
- Table 2a: 456, Tag2
- Table 2b: 456, NULL, NULL

What I have:

```
 --Query 1
 SELECT KEY, TagName, DS_KEY, Make, Model
 FROM Table1a
 JOIN Table1b
 ON Table1a.KEY = Table1b.DS_KEY
 Where TagName = 'Tag1'
```

RESULT(123, Tag1, 123, Test1, Model1)

```
 --Query 2
 SELECT KEY, TagName, DS_KEY, Make, Model
 FROM Table2a
 JOIN Table2b
 ON Table2a.KEY = Table2b.DS_KEY
 Where TagName = 'Tag2'
```

RESULT(456, Tag2, 456, NULL, NULL)

Returns the mix that I want to work with.  Getting baffled on how to Update Table2b from this point.  Can't join them (at least I don't see how!).  Maybe UNION ALL?  really hope I don't need to

```
  Update Table2b 
  Set Table2b.Make = 
  (SELECT Make FROM Table1a
  JOIN Table1b
  ON Table1a.KEY = Table1b.DS_KEY)
  FROM Table2a
  JOIN Table2b
  ON Table2a.KEY = Table2b.DS_KEY
  Where Table2a.TagName = 'Tag2'
```

Like I said, I have about 100 records to set and it just seems like there needs to be an easier way.  Thanks in advance and please excuse any syntax errors as I'm trying to paraphrase the question to keep it simple (and I'm tired!) :)

Comment: Here's a sample to work with. Let me know if this doesn't work as I've never used SQL Fiddle!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db2fa/4

Comment: Can anyone give some insight here please?

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you want to update one table with values from another table, the syntax is like this:

```
UPDATE TableA SET TableA.Value = TableB.Value 
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Key = TableB.Key
```

Comment: That's true, but I can't see how I can join the Table1a/Table1b and Table2a/Table2b data since there is no common KEY to join between them

Comment: Well, in that case, your question is really a matter of matching records between two tables? Post some examples of the contents of your tables and how you would like the records to be matched, and maybe someone here can help you out in writing a proper JOIN criteria.

Comment: First time doing this, so I hope this link works! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db2fa/4

Comment: Is that sample sufficient Dan?  If not, I can add more or try to recreate the actual tables (Prob be a lot of work though!)

Comment: @FrankandBeans Let me see if I understand you correctly: You want to update Table2b, so that the record with Key1 = 456 has its other columns (Make and Model) updated to match those of Table1b with Key1 = 123. Is this correct? I would guess that you have more than just the one record in Table2b that needs to be updated - so given a Key1 from Table1b, what should the Key1 in Table2b be? And what is the point of Table1a and Table1b - as I see it, they don't provide any useful information.

Comment: Ya, there are many more records to work with here, just trying to keep the chat simple.  Been so busy with other things, it took me forever to get back to this!  You're on the right track.  In this example, Table2b would end up with the Make/Model from Table1b.  Table2b = 123, Test1, Model1.  My query would be linking Tag1 to Tag2 by user input.  So, User sets the source Tag name and destination Tag name for his 'copy' feature.  It really sucks that the keys can't be used to line stuff up, but that's what makes life interesting!  Again, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a linking table to correlate Tag1 to Tag2. Change your fiddle as below:
To you schema add:

```
create table linking_table
(
  PK int not null primary key,
  TagName_a varchar(50),
  TagName_b varchar(50)
  )
insert into linking_table (PK, TagName_a, TagName_b)
values (1,'Tag1','Tag2')
```

and then query 2 becomes:

```
SELECT Table2a.KEY1,Table2a.TagName,Table2b.DS_KEY, Table1b.Make, Table1b.Model
FROM (Table2a
JOIN Table2b
ON Table2a.KEY1 = Table2b.DS_KEY)
JOIN linking_table
ON Table2a.TagName = linking_table.TagName_b
JOIN (Table1a
JOIN Table1b
ON Table1a.KEY1 = Table1b.DS_KEY)
ON Table1a.TagName = linking_table.TagName_a
```

to give the correct output